# Jquery mobile rendering issue in webpart page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, mobile

I have below HTML inside html file which is referred in webpart page CEWP. Though this works fine as independant html page, while rendering in sharepoint , it is somehow showing up data-ico attribute text. Can you pls help out in pinpoinintg the issue. Code is simple jQuery mobile demo in sharepoint.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Registration</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="home">
       <header data-role="header">
            <h1>Register</h1>
       </header>
       <div data-role="main"  class="ui-content">
           <div data-role="fieldcontain">
               <label for="Services"  class="ui-hidden-accessible " >
                   Country:
               </label>
               <select name="Services" id="Services" data-native-menu="false" data-mini="true" multiple="multiple" size="4">
                   <option>Country</option>
                   <option value="hotel">Hotel</option>
                   <option value="transport">Transport</option>
                   <option value="others">Others</option>
               </select>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `content`  in a CSS `:after` or `:before` rule gets the class value.

```
[selector]::after{
                   content:class
                 }
```

*I presume you copy/paste code and not understand what you are doing*

**Start by using current jQuery versions, you are using 4 to 5 year old versions...**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery#Release_history
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_Mobile#Release_history

Comment: You are right Danny, i did copy the code and dont have much understanding. However, referencing latest jquery files doesnt make any difference and shows same output. so I was wondering why same code works in plain HTML ,but breaks when added in the sharepoint page. I feel thats valid question , irrespective of i copy code write it myself.

Comment: Now you ruled out jQuery, you have to check (hunt for) which CSS rule changes your UI... F12 Developer Tools